# Sun, Audio-player and Sound I/O

Tags: java, javasound, jmf, sun, audio-player

I have a few questions related to Sun, Audio-player and Sound Input/Output

Why is the `sun.audio.AudioPlayer` package not part of the Java API? Some info is here instead: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6b14/sun/audio/AudioPlayer.java Yet it is still part of the default JDK build I am using.

I have tried using JMF and spent half the day screw balling around with it, to no real avail. I managed to import the `jmf.jar` into Eclipse I tried a demo script and it still spat out errors like nobody business. Considering its abandoned now?!? Java does however provide a  link for a relatively new version: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html I am a little concerned however how at the bottom of the page the following is written "false,,,,,,,"?

Whats the best package to use for audio I/O and manipulation in your opinion?

I just want to work on a project and I though an MP3 player would be a nice place to start as I can do a little swing. However it seems to be rather difficult as from what I have read  Java is not really very keen on making mp3 and audio manipulation packages.

Comment: Many independent game programmers use ogg compression instead of mp3. There are good third-party decoders. There are also some nice little libraries such as TinySound that allow mixing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### sun.audio is undocumented

Like other `sun.*` packages, it is undocumented and it might disappear.

### Java Media Framework is old

It's an optional package, not part of the SE and hasn't been updated in a long time. Oracle has a page on it and it's still available but, well, who knows what will happen to it.

### javax.sound is part of the SE

This is the current Java sound implementation, it is part of the SE and the tutorial for it can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/). If you want to use audio in Java this is what you should learn because it's official, it works, it gets updated sometimes and it is well-documented.

### javax.sound does not play mp3

Why is that? Despite being ubiquitous in file systems, mp3 has a history of [licensing and patent issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Licensing_and_patent_issues). Mp3 is a minefield and this may be why Sun/Oracle has not put effort in to supporting it. (If this is why, I don't blame them.)

If you really want to play mp3 there are some third-party decoders floating around on the web. There is no point in recommending one because all of them will read mp3.

---

### JavaFX does play mp3

Use a [`javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html). See [`javafx.scene.media`/Supported Media Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html#SupportedMediaTypes). JavaFX is part of the JRE/JDK as of Java 8 (and new versions of Java 7) and will (probably) eventually supersede several SE APIs like `javax.sound` and `javax.swing`.

Comment: Great, good solid answer. Hard to tell left from right some times when looking for a specific answer over the thousands of other posts on Java and Audio functionality...I was actually reading up on the javax.sound.* package whilst I was waiting for a reply.

Comment: *"javax.sound does not play mp3"*  All it lacks is an SPI for MP3.  JMF has one.  See the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for details.

Comment: Hey, you nailed it. `sun.audio` has been removed from Java starting with JDK 9. Bug report [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050465). I used to have some code that used `sun.audio` that worked on JDK 8, but once I migrated to JDK 9, that code stopped working and I started using JavaFX media player capability. However, now that JavaFX has been unbundled from the JDK starting in Java 11, it might not be a great idea to bring in JavaFX *just* to play a simple audio clip.