# Eclipse Java - could not create audiodata object

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, javasound

Trying to convert into spectrum but first I needed to play music but when I clicked the button "could not create audio data object" appears so I needed some help for my project.

```
package sounds;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

import sun.audio.*;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;

public class Frame {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AudioPlayer MGP;
                    AudioStream BGM;
                    AudioData MD;
                    Frame window = new Frame();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Frame() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
            AudioStream BGM;
            AudioData MD;
            ContinuousAudioDataStream loop=null;

            try{

                BGM =new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("georgia.wav"));
                MD=BGM.getData();
                loop = new ContinuousAudioDataStream (MD);


                            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }  

            MGP.start(loop);

            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use 'sun.audio' classes - http://stackoverflow.com/q/22031701/2670892

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for replying sir, what am i supposed to use? sorry im very new to this.

Comment: Look at the [javasound tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info)