# I cannot import sun.audio

Tags: java, audio, importerror

I´m trying to simply play background musik using sun.audio. However for some reason, I´m not able to import it. I tried the following lines

```
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.*;
```

and both times it sais "The import sun.audio cannot be resolved".
I also tried just starting to write code with it, as eclipse then proposes quick fixes, including imports. But that also did not work out.
I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: Sun packages may have been cleaned out in modern versions of java and you may need to bring them yourself.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen and how do I do that? Do I have to download some kind of repair software or would it be best to use other ways of implementing sounds?

Comment: I don't believe it is downloadable.  According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031701/sun-audio-player-and-sound-i-o, the solution is to recode your application to use the `javax.sound` APIs.  (The `sun.sound` APIs were removed in Java 9.)

Comment: Ok I´ll try using that instead. Thank´s a lot